# WPF layout problems using Grid and ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid-layout

I'm (sort of) a newbie in WPF. And I'm stuck with this layout. The Viewbox is displayed fine and so is the space (30%) for ListBox but I can't see ListBox in that space. Following is my XAML, just pertaining to the problem.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=thisControl}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Viewbox>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeOtherProperty}" Utils:ListBoxExtenders.AutoScrollToEnd="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `DataContext` defined at a wrong level. `SomeOtherProperty` is part of that context without which no data will be bound to the ListBox. But I'm still perplexed as to why there wasn't any binding error in the Output Window for it. Hmmm...